# Is there any GUI for Stockfish which allows comments in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: stockfish, macos

Currently I use the built-in Stockfish app that's in the Apple Store. But unfortunately, I can't put comments in the moves. I would really appreciate it if you can give me good recommendations other than ScidvsMac, because after updating to Big Sur, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I'm also curious about this - Chess notation on the mac... > Currently I use the built-in Stockfish app that's in the Apple Store. But unfortunately, I can't put comments in the moves. ? Are you notating games, puzzles or both?

Comment: Repertoire! and sometimes games. But mostly repertoire just to have an idea of natural moves in some openings.

Comment: For the people who are hitting the "close" button, if you think the question is a duplicate, then please refer me to the link. And if you have an answer, then please type it here. Otherwise, I don't see a reason behind hitting the "close" button for this question!

Answer (score 1):

I found ChessX to be working well. I can put comments in the moves. But I still don't know how to make the depth of Stockfish to run more than 20! It only runs for 3 seconds, then it stops. If I can figure out how to make it run longer, I would be happy with ChessX.

Edit: You can slide the bar at the bottom right corner to make the search deeper